# Why is a ScrolledPanel inside a Treebook not resized automatically?

Tags: python, scroll, wxpython, panel, autoresize

As I need scrollbars I changed the default Panel by a ScrolledPanel, but the content I inserted inside ScrolledPanel does not make it auto-size according to the size of the window.

I then tried to create a default Panel and insert all the widgets in it through a BoxSizer and finally through another BoxSizer insert this Panel inside the ScrolledPanel, but the content continues without doing the autoresize.

I also tried the opposite, that is, I created a standard Panel and inserted inside my ScrolledPanel using the BoxSizers, but also did not work.

Another detail is that this ScrolledPanels must be inside a TreeBook, because I have a tree that manages the call of each ScrolledPanel.

My code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

from gettext import gettext as _

class MyMainView(wx.Frame):

    instance = None
    init = 0

    def __init__(self, app):
        if self.init:
            return

        self.frameWidth = 850
        self.frameHeight = 600
        self.init = 1

        no_sys_menu = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.CLOSE_BOX
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=_("Title"), style=no_sys_menu)
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(self.frameWidth, self.frameHeight))

        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.Centre()

        treeBook = Treebook(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(treeBook, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()
        self.Layout()

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = wx.Frame.__new__(self)
        elif not self.instance:
            self.instance = wx.Frame.__new__(self)

        return self.instance


class Treebook(wx.Treebook):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Treebook.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)

        self.AddPage(MainPanel(self), _("AppTitle"))
        self.AddSubPage(MenuPanel(self), _("SubNodeTitle1"))
        self.ExpandNode(0)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel): # This Panel is OK

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        self.font1 = wx.Font(18, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
        self.font2 = wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)

        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

        pngIcon = wx.Image("foo.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        icon = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, pngIcon, pos=(25, 15), size=(pngIcon.GetWidth(), pngIcon.GetHeight()))

        titleHelp = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("HelpTitle"))
        titleHelp.SetFont(self.font1)

        titleApp = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("AppTitle"), pos=(25, 85))
        titleApp.SetFont(self.font1)

        description = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("App description."), pos=(25, 170))
        description.SetFont(self.font2)

        features = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("App features."), pos=(25, 210))
        features.SetFont(self.font2)

        pngLogo = wx.Image("foo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        logo = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, pngLogo, pos=(25, 390), size=(pngLogo.GetWidth(), pngLogo.GetHeight()))

        sliLine = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, style=wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)
        sliLine.SetSize(wx.Size(625, 1))

        steCopy = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Copyright text."))
        steCopy.SetFont(self.font2)

        heigthSpacer = 20

        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hSizer.Add(icon, 0, wx.LEFT, 0)
        hSizer.Add(titleHelp, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 10)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.LEFT, 10)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer + 10)
        vSizer.Add(titleApp, 0, wx.LEFT, 15)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(10)
        vSizer.Add(description, 0, wx.LEFT, 15)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(features, 0, wx.LEFT, 15)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(115)
        vSizer.Add(logo, 0, wx.LEFT, 15)
        vSizer.Add(sliLine, 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 15)
        vSizer.Add(steCopy, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 15)

        self.SetSizer(vSizer)


class MenuPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel): # This panel does not fit content within the size of the Treebook panel

    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

        self.font1 = wx.Font(18, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
        self.font2 = wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
        self.font3 = wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)

        strTitlePage = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("TitlePanel"))
        strTitlePage.SetFont(self.font1)

        strIntroPage = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
        strIntroPage.SetFont(self.font2)

        png = wx.Image("foo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, pos=(240, 100), size=(png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))

        steMainTitle = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("MainMenu"))
        steMainTitle.SetFont(self.font3)

        steMainMenu = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
        steMainMenu.SetFont(self.font2)

        png = wx.Image("foo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, pos=(240, 100), size=(png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))

        steLangTitle = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Config Menu"))
        steLangTitle.SetFont(self.font3)

        steLangMenu = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
        steLangMenu.SetFont(self.font2)

        png = wx.Image("foo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        bitmap3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, pos=(240, 100), size=(png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))

        stePortMenu = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
        stePortMenu.SetFont(self.font2)

        png = wx.Image("foo.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        bitmap4 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, pos=(240, 100), size=(png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))

        steHelpTitle = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Menu Help"))
        steHelpTitle.SetFont(self.font3)

        steHelpMenu = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
        steHelpMenu.SetFont(self.font2)

        sliLine = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, style=wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)

        steCopy = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Copyright text."))
        steCopy.SetFont(self.font2)

        heigthSpacer = 20

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(strTitlePage, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(strIntroPage, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(steMainTitle, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(bitmap1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(steMainMenu, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(steLangTitle, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(bitmap2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(steLangMenu, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(bitmap3, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(stePortMenu, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(steHelpTitle, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(bitmap4, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL, 5)
        vSizer.Add(steHelpMenu, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.AddSpacer(heigthSpacer)
        vSizer.Add(sliLine, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        vSizer.Add(steCopy, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)

        self.SetSizer(vSizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    main = MyMainView(app)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I want is to click on an item in the tree and open next to a Panel with the content being resized according to the size of my window (statictexts, staticlines).

Comment: It would be much more helpful if we could just paste and run the code sample... (undefined helpController)

Comment: Forgive my failure @PetrBlahos. I adjusted the code and it is now functional. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but:

- StaticText won't automatically break lines, so even if the "inner panel" resized correctly, the texts would not be visible. You might want to use TextCtrl of some kind, possibly a rich-text ctrl.
- If you have a scrolled panel, then the inside of the panel has whatever size it needs, and scrolled panel just adds scroll bars.

So, what you need is: Make another panel inside the MenuPanel, and make all the widgets in the MenuPanel children of this new panel. Then add an on-size handler for the MenuPanel

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

def OnSize(self, evt):
    evt.Skip(False)
    self.p.SetSize(evt.GetSize())
```

(self.p is the new panel inside the MenuPanel). But this sets the size of the panel so no scroll bars will ever be needed.  You probably want only the vertical scrollbar and only when it is needed, right? Then I would probably try to set the width of the window only if it is possible, or set the width and very big height, measure, and set the size again.